# Displaying image in sliding menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, slidingmenu

I have small question. How to display profile picture and UserFullName and State and Country in single label dynamically from a service in sliding menu like below attached image.[image] TIA

Comment: Simply you can do in uitable view custom cell,if you show the data in list(table view)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `UserFullName`, `State` and `Country` in single label. You need to use two labels, set image like your attached pic, and round corners.

For example:

```
Imageview.layer.cornerRadius=10;
[Imageview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Design `tablecell` like this or you can also design `UIView` in sidebar like same.

Programmatically set `corner radius` of image so it's look round.

[image]

Comment: This is already done. but i need to display profile picture in image view , userfullname in 1st label and state&Country in another label from a service

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set all in one label expect to imageview

do this

```
[_demolabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" UserFullName \n State Country"]];
```

And apply your suitable logic for label height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Image you can not add in Label, you need a separate outlet for Image.

Displaying in single label is bit tricky. You have to use NSAttributted Text. After reading the name of the user needed to append a \n to truncate the next line data.

label.numberOFLines = 0; (you have to set this for label)

Best option Use two label one for User name and next one is for location give proper auto layout and spacing between them, then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Cell you can get the image,name,state and country

First you need to create Custom UITableView Cell.In xib file you need to set ImageView,name label and staecountry label also connect(drag in .h).

please import the Quartzcore framework for forming circle

```
   #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

in TableView DataSource Methods

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return yourArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
  if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }


   cell.imgViewDetail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"];


   cell.imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
   cell.imgView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
   cell.imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


   cell.labelName.text = @"James Stevens";
   cell.labelStateCountry.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"Sydney",@"Australia"];
   return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 80;
}
```

> Important - You have to give imageView width and height as 200,200 or 100,100 or 50,50....whatever you want to give equal width and height when you set imageView as circle